# Почему специфически-канцелярский пишется через дефис?

Tags: орфография, сложные-прилагательные

Это термин? В каком словаре можно проверить написание? В большинстве случаев слово ***специфически*** является наречием и пишется раздельно.

Существуют еще термины с дефисным написанием этой основы и как их отличить от сочетания наречия и прилагательного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, во всех случаях слово специфически пишется отдельно от следующего слова. На Грамоте.ру несколько раз встречалось неправильное написание, после чего им был задан вопрос по этому поводу (Вопрос № 274196). В ответе Грамота.ру признала правильность раздельного написания и, вроде, собиралась привести всё к единому написанию.

См. также ответ на Вопрос № 241191.

Answer (score 2):

*Специфически канцелярский* пишется раздельно.

Вот выдержка из книги ["Культура русской речи. Учебник для вузов"](http://bibl.tikva.ru/base/B1451/B1451Part98-493.php):
"В тексте наблюдаются канцеляризмы: формула с причинно-следственным значением *В* *связи с...* и **специфически канцелярский** устаревший оборот (оплачено) *в полной сумме".*

Вот ещё пример: *...машинка, изображенная под номером один, использовалась в основном в банках (используется ли сейчас, не знаю, но вряд ли), а устройство под номером шесть – **специфически бухгалтерское.***
[Загадочные канцелярские приспособления](https://habr.com/post/178155/)

В орфографическом словаре (110 тысяч слов, 1957) не обнаружилось ни одного слова, которое бы начиналось с конструкции с дефисом (*специфически-...*).
Не обнаружились такие "конструкции" и в других словарях (печатных и "сетевых").

Это ошибочное написание (через дефис) появилось на "Грамоте" и теперь кочует с сайта на сайт, обрастая ссылками (см. [Вопрос № 292686](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE&start=75) и ["про Москву"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/hot10)).

Решение "Грамоты" таково:
Спасибо, привели к единому написанию (без дефиса, раздельно).
Корректно: специфически групповой (в знач. "свойственный только группе"), специфически правовые [а значит, и специфически канцелярский].
[**Вопрос № 274196**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83&start=75)

Answer (score 1):

Я допускаю *авторское* написание через дефис в смягчённом значении "изощрённо-канцелярский" (стиль речи, ответ персонажу и т. п.). В этом случае первая часть изменяет *свойства* основного прилагательного, в то время как при обычном, раздельном написании оно лишь указывает на *принадлежность* чего-то "канцелярскому" (значение "сугубо канцелярский" подход, стиль).

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что терминологический оттенок здесь присутствует, но это должно быть отражено в правилах. Я не думаю, что в этой теме возможна авторская орфография.